Time-dependent perturbation theory for hydrogen atom transition
My question specifically concerns the hydrogen atom. I need to find the transition probability from the initial state $|2,1,1\rangle$ to the states with $n=3$ under the perturbation $\hat V(t)=\frac{\omega_0}{a_0}e^{-t/\tau}\hat{r} \hat{L}_x$ for a time $T\gg\tau$, with $a_0$ being the Bohr radius, $\omega_0=\frac{eB_0}{2mc}$, $B_0=10^8 V/m$, and $\tau = 10^{-9}s$.
Of course, the exercise requires an explicit calculation, but I was wondering what I should look at and compare to immediately say that the probability will be very low or even to estimate its order of magnitude. Can this be done right away? Clearly, I don’t mean to suggest that such a prediction is absolutely possible, but perhaps without referring to the specific data of the exercise, is there something general we can say about transitions between states of different $n$ of the hydrogen atom?
If I were to make a bit more progress, setting aside the tedious calculations with radial functions for now (which allow the transition only to $|3,1,0\rangle$ state using the orthogonality of the spherical harmonics) the first-order result, after performing the time integral, is:
$$\mathcal{P} = \left|\frac{\omega_0}{a_0\hbar} \cdot \frac{\langle f\,|\,\hat r \hat L_x|\,i \rangle}{\tau^{-1}-i\omega_{fi} }  \right|^2 \cdot4\sin^2\left(\frac{\omega_{fi}T}{2}\right)$$
Perhaps I can say something here? Should I just compare $\tau^{-1}=10^{9}s^{-1}$ and $\omega_{fi}\approx 1.8eV\approx 10^{16}s^{-1}$? I can't really guess the magnitude of $\langle 3,1,0\,|\,\hat{r} \hat{L}_x|\,2,1,1\rangle$.

Well... this is first order perturbation theory so you know by assumption that the probability has to be small else you'd need to go to higher order.
This being said, your not going to get help by comparing $\omega_{fi}$ and $\tau$: once you take the modulus squared this factor produces $\omega_{fi}^2+\frac{1}{\tau^2}$ in the denominator, and this is a sum rather than a difference.  With your numbers, the $\tau^{-1}$ factor doesn't do much.  Thus, you're left with $T$ and in particular $\omega_{fi} T$.  You're not given much guidance there and you can't really integrate from $0$ to $\infty$ because of the sine factor.
Now, when I look back on a slightly different but similar problem where the spatial part is different but the time part is the same, I don't get the sine factor: rather I have an integral of the type
$$
\int_0^\infty dt' e^{i (\omega_{fi}-1/\tau)t'} = -\frac{1}{i\omega_{fi}-\frac{1}{\tau}}
$$
which doesn't contain an oscillating part. (I may have messed up the signs somewhere but this doesn't change my conclusion: I don't get an oscillating term.)  This makes sense as your perturbation is exponential rather than periodic, and that would produce a probability that depends only on the spatial part of your system: after a very long time, your perturbation dies away so the system stays in a given state rather than oscillate in an out.
Under this scenario, the probability now depends essentially on $\omega/a_0\hbar$ times your spatial matrix element, which should be of size $\sim \hbar a_0$.  Thus the probability would depend on $(\omega_0 /\omega_{fi})^2$ (or something like this).
